# Human-readable value of choice field on serialize

Tags: django

I'm sending serialized data of a queryset into my templates, like so:

```
from django.core import serializers

def View(request):
    invoices = serializers.serialize('json', Invoice.objects.all())
    context = {'invoices':invoices}
    return render(request, r'template_folder\template.html', context)
```

However my choice fields are being parsed as the actual value and not the human-readable value

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    (...)
    transaction_number = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    invoice_amount = models.FloatField()
    office = models.IntegerField(choices = [(1, 'ABC'), (2, 'DEF')])
```

```
    <script>
        const invoices = JSON.parse("{{invoices|escapejs}}")
    </script>
```

What can i do to send the human-readable value to the template ('ABC', 'DEF'..) instead of the ('1', '2'..)?

Answer (score 0):

You use the Django's inbuilt functionality for doing that.

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}    
 {{ invoice.get_office_display }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That would only work if i wanted only that field. I'm rendering the whole model object.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. You have to then render them in a for loop. See edited answer.

Comment: But getting the office display would only show me that field right (office)? Check my edit please. My model has more fields and the idea is to get the detailed description of every instance in the model.

If i was not clear, what i meant is that i need the other fields such as invoice_amount for example.

Comment: The "get_office_display" gets your choices 'ABC' 'DEF' etc. If you want other data from the same model you can use `{{invoice.invoice_amount}}` or `{{invoice.transaction_number}}`